# Java Calendar Configuration

Tags: java, calendar

I am using the Calendar object as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

I want the result of this to be 24, as opposed to 0. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Because [there is a new API for time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all, the time 24:00 is a valid time according to ISO-8601 and means midnight start at the next day.**

**`java.util.GregorianCalendar` does not support the hour 24.** Please feel free to study following example code with my comments:

```
// By default lenient behaviour with overflow of 24:00 to next day
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.AUGUST, 17, 0, 0, 0);
gcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
System.out.println("HOUR_OF_DAY: " + gcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); // 0
System.out.println(sdf.format(gcal.getTime())); // 2014-08-14 00:00

// now switch to strict mode    
gcal.setLenient(false);
gcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
gcal.getTime(); // triggers recomputation which will fail with following abort
// abort relates to set()-method => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY
```

**Most other libraries do not support setting the time to 24:00, too.** Neither Java-8-time nor its predecessor Joda-Time give support. However, Java-8-time can [parse such times](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--) but never set.

**My library Time4J partially allows setting this time**, namely for the type [PlainTime](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainTime.html) which indeed has an extended value range from 00:00 until 24:00 (inclusive). However, I have decided to handle it differently for the type `PlainTimestamp`(combination of calendar date and wall time) because I want to preserve a bijective unique mapping between timestamp and a single incrementing counter (otherwise the values 2014-08-17 24:00 and 2014-08-18 00:00 would stand for the same timestamp counter causing problems in sorting). The Time4J-solution for this problem is here automatic normalization (with overflow similar to lenient behaviour in the class `GregorianCalendar`).

Answer (score 2):

If you set the field Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY to be 24, then it is set to 0 of the next day.
the 24th hour of a day does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command

Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
does the conversion from am/pm to 24H so you don't need to add anything else.